# Reflection - get method for a nullable<datetiime>

Tags: c#, reflection, db2

While there are similar questions in Stackoverflow about this it does not help me with my problem.
Here is the big picture of what I am doing.  I am generating IL for my iDB2DataReader to dynamically get my types from a database and map to my poco.
I am having problems getting a nullable to pull in the data.

So I have a method that needs to return the methodinfo via reflection. To get the this I am using "getmethod" of the type that I need.
Here is the code:

```
private static MethodInfo GetDataMethod(Type destinationDataType, Type underlyingDestinationDataType, iDB2DataReader reader)
{
    MethodInfo methInfo = null;

    if (_readerDataMethods.ContainsKey(destinationDataType))
    {
        methInfo = _readerDataMethods[destinationDataType];
    }
    else
    {

        if (underlyingDestinationDataType != null)
        {
            //trying to get underlying type which would be DateTime thus resulting in GetDatetime.
            methInfo = reader.GetType().GetMethod("Get" + underlyingDestinationDataType.Name);
        }
        else
            methInfo = reader.GetType().GetMethod("Get" + destinationDataType.Name);
        //methInfo = reader.GetType().GetMethod("Get" + destinationDataType.ToGenericTypeString());

        if (methInfo != null)
        {
            _readerDataMethods[destinationDataType] = methInfo;
        }
    }

    return methInfo;
}
```

As you can see from my code comment I get the underlying type of datetime but this does not work, it gets a runtime error of "Operation could destabilize the runtime.".

The real problem is I don't know what the name I should be using for the getmethod for a `Nullable<DateTime>`.  Or at least I was hoping it was that simple.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't it up to *you* what naming convention you use for your methods? It's not really clear what type exposes these methods...

Comment: @Stanley -  I did try that but fails as well.

Comment: @jon - good point you cant tell that the type is Nullable<DateTime> and the name property of the type is "getDateTime".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably going to have to create a special case fur Nullables as the actual type name wouldn't be valid in a method name.  I'd check to see if it's a Nullable type and the use reflection to get the generic parameter.

Example:

```
Type t = typeof (Nullable<DateTime>);

Console.WriteLine(t.Name);   // Nullable`1
if (t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
{
    Type t2 = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t);
    Console.WriteLine("Nullable"+t2.Name); // NullableDateTime
}
```

Comment: Can you share an example of what you mean? I do check if it of nullable type as underlyingDestinationDataType is null if it is not.

Comment: I just tried this methInfo = reader.GetType().GetMethod("GetNullableDateTime"); just hard coded this string but this returned null.

Comment: Then take out the `Nullable` and just check for null first; if the source value is Null set the destination to null otherwise set it to the value.

Comment: While the above code is not what fixed my problem your answer pointed me in the right direction and the above comment was the real answer I needed.  If it is null simply set it as null and if Datetime then use the "getDatetime".  I was making it more complex then it needed to be THANKS!!